# What is time complexity of Python3's open() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the time complexity in Big O notation of Python3's `open()` function when appending to a file?

For example, the following line: `with open("HugeDocument.csv", "a") as f`

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be O(1). The OS knows where the file starts and it knows its size, so knowing where to start writing should be O(1) (assuming `n` here would be the file size or "length")

Comment: I assume you mean complexity with respect to the size of the file to be opened--and if so, that depends on the filesystem involved. I agree with DeepSpace that most modern Linux filesystems should do this in O(1) time, but there's no reason they have to. And of course this has nothing to do with Python or any other programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my understanding the `open()` function returns a file object which is a pointer/handle to the actual resource on the disk. Hence the complexity of `open()` should be constant, since the location of the file is passed into the `open(file='abc')` function.

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object

> An object exposing a file-oriented API (with methods such as read() or write()) to an underlying resource. Depending on the way it was created, a file object can mediate access to a real on-disk file or to another type of storage or communication device (for example standard input/output, in-memory buffers, sockets, pipes, etc.).

Performing operations using the file object will have different complexity depending on the type of operation (like `read()`, `readline()`, `seek()`), the file size, system memory limits and other File System configurations.

Comment: Indeed - as far as "time complexity" is concerned, file openning is O(1). Depending on the underlying filesystem and what calls are available for it, oppening for append might depend on the current file-size - but that would only take place if the O.S. would expose an exotically connected data source with a filesystem emulation on top, that would have to actually read all file contents in order to be able to write to its end. Even then, the  lengthy part would likely take place on `.write`, not on `open`.